# How to insert an ACF get_field inside a javascript anchor?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need to insert an ACF URL. Using javascript seemed like a good idea but I cant get the href to populate.

I tried using ACF PHP inside an innerHTML javascript command. The icon shows up but the href does not.

```
<script>document.getElementById('bio_linkedin_btn').innerHTML = '<a href="<?php echo the_field('linkedin_izan'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>\n';</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`the_field()` function echoes the content for you. Just use the_field().

```
<script>document.getElementById('bio_linkedin_btn').innerHTML = '<a href="<?php the_field('linkedin_izan'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>\n';</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately it still does not populate. Funny thing is that replacing your code with "google.com" does work. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Set the WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php file to true and check what is the error showing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the ID of the post to second parameter. Also you do not need to echo if you're using `the_field()`.

```
<?php the_field('linkedin_izan', get_the_ID()); ?>
```

OR

```
<?php echo get_field('linkedin_izan', get_the_ID()); ?>
```

If any of the above does not work try this. Add a hidden div and echo the ACF field inside the data-url attribute

```
<div id="theURL" hidden data-url="<?php echo get_field( 'linkedin_izan', get_the_ID() ); ?>"></div>
```

Then, get the value to your javascript

```
var el = document.querySelector('#theURL');
var yourURL = el.getAttribute('data-url'));
console.log(yourURL);

document.getElementById('bio_linkedin_btn').innerHTML = '<a href="'+yourURL+'"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>\n';
```

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately it still does not populate. Funny thing is that replacing "<?php the_field('linkedin_izan', get_the_ID()); ?>
"  with "https://www.google.com" does work.

Comment: I updated my answer above. This way you will echo the ACF value on data-url and using getAttribute() on javascript you can get your url. This should do it.